# python sending specific number of commands from a text file

Tags: python, command, send, gnu-screen

I have a text file that contains 100 bash commands and i want to execute every 5 in a new screen , but I don't know if I can use "for" in this case .

For example we have those commands :-

```
mkdir 1
cd 1
rm -rf 1.txt
rm -rf 2.txt
cd ..
mkdir2
...
```

I want to create a new screen and send the first 5 commands to it to be executed and then send the other 5 to another screen to the end of the file .

How I can do that ? any help please with the coding ?

Comment: what? you want to spawn a new screen every 5 commands? why are you doing that? why dont you just redirect the output to a file or something?

Comment: the commands that i am sending will take a long time as it is dealing with a huge files . I just wrote this as an example . The python script is just automate the process for the whole commands

Comment: What have you tried?  Python has a [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: I used `os.system("scren -m -d {0}".format(line))` but this sends every line in the text to a new screen , I want to send each 5 togather

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point why to do this, but you can use your solution in combination with buffering 5 lines from input and joining them by `;`:

```
with open('commands.sh') as file:
    buffer = []
    for i, command in enumerate(file):
        buffer.append(command)
        if i % 5 == 0:
            os.system('screen -m -d "{0}"'.format(';'.join(buffer)))
            buffer = []
```